# disable keyboard for one of the text fields in a table view

Tags: iphone

Hi i am new to the iphone developement.Kindly help me out.
I want to disable the keyboard for one of text field in a table view.I have assigned a pickerview to that particular field.So i need just the pickerview and not the keyboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
  if(textField== mTextField)
  {
    return NO;
  }
return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your View Controller or more to implement UITextFieldDelegate and set them to be a delegate of your UITextField.
And then, you should implement `(BOOL) textField: shouldChangeCharactersInRange: replacementString:` function and return NO value always form it.